# why is ifcfg-lo renamed to vmimport.ifcfg-lo when importing a linux image to AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I notice that when importing a linux image to EC2 via vmimport, the file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo will be renamed to vmimport.ifcfg-lo, which results failure in local traffic, i.e. you can't even ping localhost. In order to have loopback interface back I have to rename the file back and run "ifup lo".

The same happens to ifcfg-eth1. But this is understandable according to AWS documentation which mentions vmimport will keep only one NIC.

Does anybody know why this would happen to the loopback interface too? Disabling the loopback interface is a strange thing to do, isn't it?

Thank you!

Mic